# Rotating Object in OpenGL ES - Correct Order to Apply Transformations ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, rotation

I am trying to rotate an object around it's center with the following code :

```
-(void)render
{
// clear the matrix
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

// move to my position

//scale
glScalef(0.000015, 0.000015, 0.000015);

xRotation =280.0;
zRotation =1.0;
yRotation +=0.5;

glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0, 0.0f);
glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

[mesh render];

//restore the matrix
glPopMatrix();

}
```

This code works correctly and the object rotates around the center. The problem is that I also have a matrix which defines the starting position of the object in the scene called matricesArray. I added a new line to my code to multiply by this matrix and place the object in its correct starting position :

```
-(void)render
{
// clear the matrix
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

// move to my position

//xRotation = 280;

//scale
glScalef(0.000015, 0.000015, 0.000015);

xRotation =280.0;
zRotation =1.0;
yRotation +=0.5;

glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0, 0.0f);
glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glMultMatrixf(matricesArray);  //This is the line I have added to apply the matrix.

[mesh render];

//restore the matrix
glPopMatrix();


}
```

The problem is that the object now rotates in a wide circle around the screen.

My question is what is the correct order to apply the matrix in my code ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first rotate then translate to the location you want it to be.

Comment: How ? The matrix (matricesArray) also contains position and rotation data ?

Comment: do glRotatef before glTranslatef

Comment: Still doesn't work - I think the glmultmatrix command is the problem.

Comment: The matrix is already edited when you do the glRotatef and glTranslatef. I think removing glMultMatrixf will fix your problem. Make sure to start your method with glLoadIdentity to reset the matrix to the identity matrix.

Comment: As per the question the matrice specifies the starting point of the object - if I remove that then the object will be in the wrong place.

Comment: so you'll need to do glLoadIdentity first then glMultMatrixf then glRotate then glTranslate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8084/discussion-between-ohnomycoco-and-ggfela)